# Responsive image height inside a flex container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I have a standard Bootstrap grid and an image inside a `.col` which height should be equal to the height of the text block to the right:

```css
.img-fluid-height {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 overflow-hidden">
    
      <img class="img-fluid-height float-right" src="https://placehold.it/1920x1280" alt="...">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      
      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expected the image to be the height of the `.col` container which height is equal to the height of the text block to the right. However, it doesn't work like this.

Comment: your expection is correct but since the image is big it's the one defining the height and the text has the same height as it

Answer (score 0):

I was assuming something else. You can do something like this with `background-size`.

```css
.background-image {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://placehold.it/1920x1280");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 overflow-hidden">
    
      <div class="background-image"></div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      
      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nah, this sqeezes the image horizontally.

Comment: @sdvnksv I'm expecting the image getting skewed is okay (from OP's expectation). Else you need to set that image as background of something. Then you can use `background cover`.

Comment: No, it's not OK. I added `overflow: hidden;` to hide the excessive width.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the image from the flow using `position:absolute` and your text will define the height then you can use `height:100%` on the image:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
    
      <img class="mh-100 mw-100 position-absolute" src="https://placehold.it/1920x1280" alt="...">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      
      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wanted to avoid the absolute positioning, however this looks like the only solution.

Comment: @sdvnksv probably there is another solution ;) .. for me you can either use absolute or use background image

Answer (score -1):

added `width:100%` Hope this helps. thanks

```css
.img-fluid-height {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 overflow-hidden">
    
      <img class="img-fluid-height float-right" src="https://placehold.it/1920x1280" alt="...">
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      
      <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
      </p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```